# onclick with two function calls takes two clicks to run both functions js

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

This is probably going to be marked as a duplicate because there are so many SO questions about this already, but I'm just unable to apply those questions answers onto my code.

I am using Razor, html, css, and javascript in my Blob storage page code.

On the left side in the image below there are three containers. When clicking on one of them they are to open up and show all their children (blobs). The first time I click one of the containers only one of the function calls run (listContainerBlobs()) and it is not the one opening the container up (showHide()).

[image]

Below is the html p-tag calling the functions onclick.

```
<p class="blob-container" onclick="showHide('@containerId', '@arrowId');listContainerBlobs('@jsonBlob', '@container.Name');"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="@arrowId"></i>  @container.Name</p>
```

The full div with C# and razor:

```
 <aside class="aside">
    <div class="aside-header">

        <i class="fa fa-plus add-container-button aside-header-icons" onclick="addContainer()"></i><i class="fa fa-search search-button aside-header-icons"></i>
        <input id="searchBox" type="text" onkeyup="search()" name="search" placeholder="Search blobs..." />
    </div>
    <div class="aside-containers">
        @foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            caretArrowNumber++;
            string arrowId = "arrowId-" + caretArrowNumber;
            containerNumber++;
            string containerId = "containerId-" + containerNumber;
            var blobs = await Model.ListContainerBlobs(container.Name);
            //var jsonBlob = Json.Serialize(blobs);
            List<object> blobObject = new List<object>();
            blobObject.Add(new
            {
                blobCount = blobs.Count,
                blobs = blobs.Select(x => new
                {
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Container = container.Name,
                    Blobtype = x.BlobType,
                    Uri = x.Uri
                })
            });

            var jsonBlob = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blobObject);

            <div class="arrow-blob-container">
                <p class="blob-container" onclick="showHide('@containerId', '@arrowId');listContainerBlobs('@jsonBlob', '@container.Name');"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="@arrowId"></i>  @container.Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="showBlob" id="@containerId">
                <div class="ml-4">
                    @foreach (var blob in blobs)
                    {
                        blobNumber++;
                        string blobId = "blobId-" + blobNumber;
                        <div>
                            <input class="blobs" id="@blobId" type="button" value="@blob.Name" onclick="downloadBlob('@blobId', '@blob.Name', '@blob.Container.Name')" />
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</aside>
```

The following code is the two functions being called on onclick:

```
<script>
function listContainerBlobs(json, container) {
    console.log("beginning");
    console.log(json);

    var arr = JSON.parse(json);

    console.log(arr);
    var blobs = document.getElementById('container-blob-display').innerHTML = "<h4>" + container + "</h4>";
    var otherDiv = document.getElementById('section-1');
    var thisDiv = document.getElementById('section-2');

    otherDiv.style.display = 'none';
    thisDiv.style.display = 'inline';

    var blobNumber = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        blobNumber++;
        var blobId = "blobId" + blobNumber;
        blobs += "<p class='search-result' id='" + blobId + "' onclick='downloadBlob('" + blobId + "', '" + arr[i].Name + "', '" + container + "')'>" + arr[i].Name + "</p>";
    }
    console.log(blobs);
}

function showHide(containerId, arrowId) {
    var c = document.getElementById(containerId);
    var a = document.getElementById(arrowId);

    if (c.style.display === "none") {
        c.style.display = "inline";
        a.className = "fa fa-caret-down";
    } else {
        c.style.display = "none";
        a.className = "fa fa-caret-right";
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tried

- commenting out the `ListContainerBlobs()`-function
- commenting out all the css
- changed from style.display = "block" to "inline" (seen in the example code)
- moved the whole script section to the top of the html
- commented out almost all code in the html except the most necessary

But `showHide()` still wouldn't run on the first click.

So currently, on the first click the `listContainerBlobs()` run and on the second click the `showHide()` runs, but I would prefer if both of them ran on the first onclick.

I appreciate all the help I can get! Thanks in advance!

P.S I'd love to do a jsfiddle but it doesn't seem to understand C# and List<> (thinking <> is a tag)

---

**Edit from Mr. Smiths solution**

It still takes two clicks for me to run both functions with this solution from Mr. Smith:

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow-blob-container">
    <p class="blob-container aside-content" id="@newContId" data-containerId="@containerId" data-arrowId="@arrowId" data-jsonBlob="@jsonBlob" data-containerName="@container.Name"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="@arrowId"></i>  @container.Name</p>
</div>
```

Js:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.aside-content').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        let ds = this.dataset;

        showHide(ds.containerid, ds.arrowid);
        listContainerBlobs(ds.jsonblob, ds.containername);
    })
});
```

This works all the way with the right ids and other values, but like I said, I still need to click two timesto get both functions to be called. First click runs `listContainerBlobs()`, second click `showHide()`.

Any ideas of why that might be?

Comment: When needing to attach multiple events I would recommend using an event listener instead of `onclick`, as for your function parameters, you could set them as `data` attributes and access them inside your functions

Comment: could you give an example on how to set the variables to data attributes (I don't fully get javascript -. -) @empiric
And would it be best to call both the other functions inside the tag.onclick function() ?

Comment: Setting the data attributes would just be HTML: `data-containerid="@containerId"` and so on. To [access these attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) you can do: `document.querySelector("@arrowId").dataset.containerid`. Something along these lines

Comment: @empiric how does `querySelector` which Id is the correct one, cause the Id is a variable where the final number  increases every loop. So does the js really know which one is the one I clicked with `@arrowId`? (gonna put a new Id on the p-tag instead but lets run with arrowId for now)

Comment: You could also use a class selector to bind an event handler on all `p` tags and use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler) inside your function to reference the element which invoked the event handler

Comment: @empiric is the solution below by mr.smith what you had in mind? My code has the same problem as before when I have gotten it to work according to the solution below.

Comment: exactly, you would need to do `document.querySelectorAll('.blob-container').forEach(` when having multiple elements, after that it would only be a matter of finding the right IDs for the function parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201994/discussion-between-empiric-and-fearlessfox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an event listener which calls your functions:

```
<div class="arrow-blob-container">
    <p class="blob-container" data-container-id="@containerId" data-arrow-id="@arrowId" data-json-blob="@jsonBlob" data-container-name="@container.Name" ><i class="fa fa-caret-right" id="@arrowId"></i>  @container.Name</p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.blob-container').forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            let dataset = e.currentTarget.dataset;

            showHide(dataset.containerId, dataset.arrowId);
            listContainerBlobs(dataset.jsonBlob, dataset.containerName);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Check this snippet:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.blob-container').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let dataset = e.currentTarget.dataset;

    console.log("containerId: " + dataset.containerId);
    console.log("arrowId: " + dataset.arrowId);
    console.log("jsonBlob: " + dataset.jsonBlob);
    console.log("containerName: " + dataset.containerName);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="arrow-blob-container">
  <button class="blob-container" data-container-id="container1" data-arrow-id="arrow1" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button1">Display dataset</button>
  <button class="blob-container" data-container-id="container2" data-arrow-id="arrow2" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button2">Display dataset</button>
  <button class="blob-container" data-container-id="container3" data-arrow-id="arrow3" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button3">Display dataset</button>
  <button class="blob-container" data-container-id="container4" data-arrow-id="arrow4" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button4">Display dataset</button>
</div>
```

This also works without querySelector which might be clearer:

```js
function onButtonClick(e) {
    let dataset = e.dataset;

    console.log("containerId: " + dataset.containerId);
    console.log("arrowId: " + dataset.arrowId);
    console.log("jsonBlob: " + dataset.jsonBlob);
    console.log("containerName: " + dataset.containerName);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-blob-container">
  <button class="blob-container" onClick="onButtonClick(this)" data-container-id="container1" data-arrow-id="arrow1" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button1">Display dataset</button>
  <button class="blob-container" onClick="onButtonClick(this)" data-container-id="container2" data-arrow-id="arrow2" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button2">Display dataset</button>
  <button class="blob-container" onClick="onButtonClick(this)" data-container-id="container3" data-arrow-id="arrow3" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button3">Display dataset</button>
  <button class="blob-container" onClick="onButtonClick(this)" data-container-id="container4" data-arrow-id="arrow4" data-json-blob="{...}" data-container-name="Button4">Display dataset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get `currentTarget` on `e`. And the browser spits out: `e ==[object MouseEvent]
contId = undefined
arrId= undefined
json = undefined
contanerName = undefined`. Also it is only the first object being clickable, not the rest.

Comment: e.currentTarget is the element that was clicked. you should be able to find the right element using that. If it is always ".blob-container", use the query selector instead.
you can access the data properties (like in your edit) via the dataset property on that element. Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: the p-tag sure is a fixed element but there will be several of them. Like i said, it is only the first one that is clickable. querySelector = `Returns the first element that is a descendant of node that matches selectors`. I dont know if this is the right way (mostly cause I don't get it to work). :thinking-face:

Comment: well, I added a snippet accessing datasets of multiple elements. hope it helps

Comment: Okay, so I have tried it out and now it is going through without any errors, though the problem with clicking 2 times still exist with both examples. darn it! Thanks though :)

Comment: You can basically call any other function you want from the listener. The error is probably somewhere inside the logic. As the question was about calling two functions with one click, please consider marking this as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201993/discussion-between-mr-smith-and-fearlessfox).

Comment: Yes, the error was in the logic. Your solution workes perfectly!